# How to copy the files alone from one location to another using Grunt-contrib-copy?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I'm trying to copy set of files and move to another location using grunt-contrib-copy, but what happens is that, it copies the whole folder structure along. Is there any way to copy the files alone? 
here is my code.

```
copy:{main:{files:[{src: ['app/scripts/**'], dest: '_public/}]}}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to set the *flatten* option.

```
copy : {
    main : {
        files: [{
            src: ['app/scripts/**'],
            dest: '_public/',
            flatten: true
        }]
    }
}
```

Comment: How come the same is not working for me, I am also trying to copy the file alone